# Keyspaces in same cassandra cluster with different passwords

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am connecting to two different keyspaces with different credentials. These keyspaces are in the same cluster.

Currently, I am needing to create two different cluster beans in my spring boot app to achieve this as the credentials are set in the cluster. Credentials are not set in the session object.

For this scenario is it right to have two separate cluster beans? Can I avoid making two different cluster beans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cassandra there is no such things as a password on the keyspace. Password is set for a user that has some roles, and then this role is given particular access to the keyspace - modify, read, etc. So to have different access rights to different keyspaces, you need to have different users, and to connect as different user from the same application, you need to have different `Cluster` objects for every user (except the case if you're using DSE with DSE Java driver, where you can have so-called proxy user).

Comment: Cool. Makes sense. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single spring Cassandra Cluster bean and create a two separate session beans by using the single cluster bean and by setting the corresponding key space while creating the session beans. A sample implementation from [spring data docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)